# Excel running slowly when Excel the active window

Tags: vba, excel

I couldn't find the answer to this issue anywhere, so I do hope you guys can help me. My excel macro goes through a couple iterations of data. It autofilters a source file, takes out information, works with the data, and does so again for about 50 times - once per person. Here's some code of what I mean, all the individual submethods work just fine and are pretty damn fast:

```
For j = 1 To names.Count
   'filter the source by name, generate sheet
   FilterName names(j) 
   'prepare data with the necessary dates
   FillMasterDates dates(), j

   Dim i As Long
   Dim ending As Long
   ending = Sheets("Daten").Rows.End(xlDown).Row
   Dim cellvalue As String

   'check dates, etc
   For i = 1 To ending
       cellvalue = Sheets("Daten").Cells(i, 1)
       If cellvalue = "" Then
           Exit For
       End If
       ColorCell (i)
       FilterDate CStr(dates(i)), names(j)
   Next i

   'user data has been successfully gathered, copy over to final sheet
   FillColumns j
Next j
```

The whole code takes about 4~ seconds to run (given that I have about 2000 rows and I create a new sheet for 50~ people), which is fine. The baffling thing is that when Excel stays my active window despite using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` (earlier in the macro, but still active at this point), the necessary time to run the macro goes up to a staggering 25~ seconds. Same input, same output. So to put it simply - run macro, tab out of excel - macro needs about 4-5 seconds to run. run macro but stay in excel and wait - 25 seconds.

I've tried `Application.WindowState = Application.WindowState`, `ActiveWindow.SmallScroll`, `DoEvents`, `Application.CalculateFull()`. I tried different calculation settings, but I do not really use any of the formula calculations innate to Excel - I have to use Excel as an interface because the source file is an *.xls file and the final output has to remain in this format.

If you need me to provide more code snippets to make sense of it, ask away. I've been stumped for a good two days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try a couple more lines to disable the calculations and alerts etc.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
Application.Calculations = xlManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

However if you really want to bypass all the background nonsense excel seems to go through dont access the sheet directly through a loop, this concept maybe tricky if your not used to it but its worth every bit, and will speed up your code so fast you will wonder why you never did it in the first place.

I dont have your code so ill just give an example of how it works

```
Dim RangeArray as Variant 'This will store your range as a values array

RangeArray = Sheet1.Range("A1:G100000").Value 'this will put the entire ranges values into the array

If Not IsArray(RangeArray) Then ExitSub 'If your range is only 1 cell it will not create an array so be careful, handle this as needed

'This Array always starts lowerbound 1, RangeArray(1,1) = First Cell
```

Now with this you can loop through your data and manipulate and modify the array just like you would with a cell or a range except there is no overhead, its just values and not objects .

Once you have done what you need all you need to do then is put the values back into the sheets range

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:G100000").value = RangeArray
```

And thats it, very simple and very effective, and this transfer from array to range is immediate no matter how big it is.

Just let me know if this helps

Thanks
Paul S

---------------NEW MESSAGE-------------------

You could try something which maybe a little excessive and risky, if your only getting this problem while the window is active and displayed how about making it invisible, the problem is if your code fails and you fail to trap an error it will remain invisible until you goto taskmanager and close it there.

```
Application.Visible = false
```

This should deactivate the window too (although i have never tested that)

this should simulate you hiding the window and just bring it back when your code has finished..

---------------NEW MESSAGE-------------------

```
Application.Windowstate = xlMinimized
```

This should do the trick :D, should have mentioned this first haha

I also just saw that you tried something similar, but the code is incorrect there, try this one

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for your answer. My current issue with just using a range and using objects to do my work is that I'd like to use the autofiltered data in a range and work with that, but so far my attempts have been unsuccessful. I understand I could shave it all down to below milliseconds, but the original 4 seconds are enough for my purposes and satisfy the customer as well. Would there be no other way to simply stop the erratic behavior? If you check my post, I already tried those code examples to disable alerts,

Comment: Haha oh god, thank you Paul! It is a little unconventional, but it works just fine. Maybe there's a less 'drastic' command to just switch the active window to another one that is currently open, say the way ALT + TAB works?

Comment: thanks mate! It works perfectly. I had been trying to get ALT TAB to work, but it's way more finnicky. You've been a great help